# Prolog - delete a member from a list

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog and I wrote this code that suppose to return all the sub-lists of a list without some member of them.

```
contained(X, Y) :-
member(M, Y).
select(M, Y, X).
```

The query I type is:

```
contained(X, [1,2]) .
```

The expected result is:

```
[1],
[2]
```

The result I get is:

```
true,
true
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you understand what `select/3` does?

Comment: it says: "Is true when List1, with Elem removed, results in List2. This implementation is determinsitic if the last element of List1 has been selected."...Doesn't it mean that X will be that list after removal?

Comment: Perhaps, also think of how you would write this without using library predicates. You can do it with three simple rules (one base case, two recursive cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you made is that you wrote a dot (**`.`**) at the end of `member(M, Y)`. this means that Prolog thinks that you wrote:

```
contained(X, Y) :-
    member(M, Y).  %% notice the dot (.) here
select(M, Y, X).
```

So you here defined `contained(X, Y)` as `member(M, Y)` and furthermore you implemented a predicate named `select(M, Y, X)` that is always true for all values for `M`, `Y` and `X`.

You can replaced the `.` with a comma (`,`) here:

```
contained(X, Y) :-
    member(M, Y),
    select(M, Y, X).
```

That being said, you do *not* need `member/2` here. In fact by using member, if the list contains duplicate values, it will result in yielding the same list multiple times.

You can just use [**`select/3`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3) here with a wildcard (`_`) on the item to remove:

```
contained(X, Y) :-
    select(_, Y, X).
```

or we can use explicit recursion:

```
contained(T, [_|T]).
contained([H|T1], [H|T2]) :-
    contained(T1, T2).
```

Comment: @ChenDoytshman note that Prolog probably gave you a lot of singleton variable warnings. You should regard those as stop-what-I'm-doing-and-fix fatal errors from now on, because you probably got one for M on line 2 and M, Y and X on line 3, which indicates that something was definitely not parsed the way you expected.